# Proving $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \, \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having trouble with a proof of this question:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \, \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n = 0$$

I know $N(0)$ is a log of epsilon with base $\frac{2}{3}$ but I can't proceed with a proof.

Comment: Remember that $log (\frac 2  3)=-log (\frac 3  2)$.

Comment: Just use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ notation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{3^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743887/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-frac2n3n)

Comment: A basic real analysis text might proceed as follows.... (1) Bernoulli's inequality, (2) $r^n \to \infty$ if $r>1$, (3) $r^n \to 0$ if $0<r<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well firstly to prove it we should use the $\epsilon-N$ definition of a limit.

**Mathematical Working**

***(This is just working, not actual proof yet, just showing how to get to proof.)***

Consider:

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Trivially:
$|(\frac{2}{3})^n-0|=|(\frac{2}{3})^n|$

Now note that $3^n>n2^n$, proof of this inequality is as following:

Let $P_k$ be the statement that for some n=k:

$3^k>k2^k$

$P_1$: $3^1 = 3$, $(1)2^1 = 2$, since $3>2$, $P_1$ is true

Now let us assume $P_k$ is true and consider $P_{k+1}$

$3^{k+1}=3*3^k>3k2^k=\frac{3}{2}k2^{k+1}$

Now note:

$\frac{3}{2}k>k+1 \implies 3k > 2k + 1 \implies k>1$

Hence:

$\frac{3}{2}k2^{k+1}>(k+1)2^{k+1} \implies 3^{k+1}>(k+1)2^{k+1}$

Thus $3^n>n2^n, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

Hence $|\frac{2^n}{3^n}|<|\frac{2^n}{n2^n}|=|\frac{1}{n}|<\epsilon$

This occurs when $n>|\frac{1}{\epsilon}|=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

**So now with this here's the proof:**

Let $N = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ where $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary but fixed.

If $n>N$ then $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. This implies $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$

Since $n>1$, $n=|n|$, thus:

$|\frac{1}{n}|<\epsilon$

Now:

$|(\frac{2}{3})^n-0|<|\frac{2^n}{2^nn}|<|\frac{1}{n}|<\epsilon$

Thus given any $\epsilon > 0, \exists N$ s.t. $|(\frac{2}{3})^n-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$.

Thus $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{2}{3})^n = 0$

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid using the logarithm, we shall use the following tactic.

Since $\frac 3 2=1+\frac 12$, using the binomial theorem, we know that
$$
\left ( \frac{3}{2}  \right ) ^n=\left ( 1+\frac{1}{2}  \right ) ^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^k>\frac{n}{2}  .     $$

Therefore $\left(\frac 2 3\right)^n<\frac 2 n\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit exists because the sequence is monotonic and bounded.

L'hopital:   $$c:=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\dfrac 23)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {2^n}{3^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {\ln2\cdot 2^n}{\ln3\cdot 3^n}=\dfrac {\ln2}{\ln3}\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {2^n}{3^n}=\dfrac {\ln2}{\ln3}\lim_{n\to\infty}(\dfrac 23)^n=\dfrac {\ln2}{\ln3}c$$.

Thus $c=0$.

(You actually don't need L'hopital.   You can just split off a factor of $\frac 23$.)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{(\frac{2}{3})^n\}$ is strictly decreasing, we only need to show that its inf is $0$.

In fact you can show that if $0<q<1$ , then $$\inf\{q^n|n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}=0$$. To prove this we assume the contrary, or $i=\inf\{q^n|n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}>0$(since the inf of the set must exist and it cannot be negative) . By the definition
of inf, exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ subject to $$i<q^n<\frac{i}{q}$$, which implies $q^{n+1}<i$, a contradiction with the definition of inf.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an uncommon method:

By this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14908/955900), $$\frac{2}{3} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\big[\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}}\big]$$

Alternatively, $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}} = \frac{1}{3}\big(\big(-\frac{1}{2}\big)^n + 2\big) = \frac{\frac{2^{n + 1} + e^{i\pi n}}{2^n}}{3}$$

Hence, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^n} \implies \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\frac{(2^{n + 1} + e^{i\pi n})^n}{2^{n^2}}}{3^n}}$$

$$\to \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\frac{1}{3^n}}{\frac{2^{n^2}}{(2^{n + 1} + e^{i\pi n})^n}}}$$.

$e^{i\pi n}$ is bounded and insignificant towards large $2^{n + 1}$ as $n \to \infty$.

$$\approx \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\frac{1}{3^n}}{\frac{2^{n^2}}{(2^{n + 1})^n}}} \to 0$$